# Flextable not printing in word

Tags: r, flextable

this is my first question on here, so apologies for any errors.

I am trying to knit a markdown document to Microsoft word, which includes a flextable. The whole markdown itself knits to word with zero error messages, yet the table itself does not appear in the document. I have done the exact same thing on other markdowns that use flextable and these appear no problem, though I have had issues before where markdowns with multiple tables will print some and not others.

I would just add the table myself since its quite small, but I have an assessment for RStudio coming up soon, and will be marked down if the lecturer tries to run the code and the table doesn't print. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is the code I have already written, I am using the latest versions of both r and RStudio:**

```
sciTotal <- dplyr::select(df, sci1.1:sci4.1)
mathTotal <- dplyr::select(df, math1.1:math3.1)

df$sciScores <- rowSums(sciTotal, na.rm = TRUE)
df$mathScores <- rowSums(mathTotal, na.rm = TRUE)`

df <- dplyr::rename(df, "Condition" = "cond")

df1 <- dplyr::select(df, sciScores, mathScores, Condition)

Table1 <- dplyr::group_by(df1, Condition) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(SciMean = mean(sciScores, na.rm = TRUE), SciSD = sd(sciScores, na.rm = TRUE), MathMean = mean(mathScores, na.rm = TRUE), MathSD = sd(mathScores, na.rm = TRUE))

df1 <- as.factor(df1$Condition)

flextable::flextable(Table1)
```

**And here are my global options, in case these are helpful:**

```
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
---

{r, include=FALSE}
#set some global options
knitr::opts_chunk$set(include=FALSE, echo=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)

#turn off scientific notation and round to 3 decimals
options(scipen=999, digits=3)

df <- read.csv("data_3.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM", na.strings=c(""))

#install.packages("flextable")
library("flextable")
library("tidyverse")
names(df)
```

all of this is based on what I have been taught in lectures and my lecturer practical examples, though I will take any advice and changes I can get. If any other information would be helpful, please let me know, Thanks!